# WebServices in the hosted solution

Tags: java, spring, architecture

This is a question about solution architecture.

Our solution has will be hosted in a private datacenter (not cloud).

Is webservice-based architecture is still applicable for such deployment? 
How good will it be instead of the monolith application approach?

Please point to articles with such architectural approach.

Comment: "Is webservice-based architecture is still applicable for such deployment?" - It is where Webservices born in first place. Difference between SOA and monolith application is a completely different story than running environment... same as "compare long and warm". Anyway question is against this site rules...

Comment: Oh, I know that the question should be more specific. Sorry. Answering your question, half of the application is EAR components running on JBoss and half are Spring Boot applications. Managing infrastructure internally is possible but I doubt that it will be great in the on-premises environment.

Comment: Yes It will be great. Still question is opinion based and is very large... There are tons of pros and cons for such topic.